# '2019-09-01' in ARM Template Key Vault Reference

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I'm using key vault references in my Arm Template. Example:

```
{
                "name": "name",
                "value": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('name'), '2019-09-01').secretUriWithVersion, ')')]",
                "slotSetting": false
              },
```

What does this date '2019-09-01' indicate?

Comment: it looks like key vault API version, but it is not necessary there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the comment is correct, it represents the `apiVersion`  - [Microsoft.KeyVault vaults/secrets 2019-09-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2019-09-01/vaults/secrets).

And it is not necessary here, you can omit it, see the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#azure-resource-manager-deployment) in the doc, something like:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('storageConnectionStringResourceId')).secretUriWithVersion, ')')]",
```

Comment: Whether or not the apiVersion is required depends on whether or not the resource being referenced is defined in the same deployment/template.  If it is not, the apiVersion is required.  As well, it determines the same of the response, so if the apiVersion defined in the template changes, that could change the response and potentially break the reference() call.